# Browser support for UTF 8 Unicode fonts of different languages

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I have a mysql table storing text using utf8_unicode_ci collation. When I retrieve that text and display it in the browser, even if the text not in English, it renders it correctly in the appropriate language although I haven't included any additional fonts manually. I've tried this with a couple of different languages and it always worked.

I'd like to know if this'd work the same way for all languages included in unicode, in all the major browsers automatically or would I need to detect what language a piece of text is in and attach the right font file to it in CSS to make sure the text is always loaded properly?

Comment: Normal scenarios everything works just fine. If you have any specific unicode items, it will be a problem. Please go through http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/htmlunicode.html

Comment: Operating systems (and/or browsers) come with a large selection of fonts for many languages these days. Only rather obscure fonts may not be installed by default. We cannot really give a comprehensive overview over which operating systems/browsers come with which fonts.

Comment: Okay thank you. Looks like I dont have to worry because I'll be working mostly with fairly common fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no fonts are specified, each browser uses its own default font and some list of backup fonts for characters not covered by the default font. While this often works nicely, it may cause a mix of fonts to be used if a document contains texts in different languages. It may also cause failures for many writing systems and less common characters, either because a user’s system has no fonts containing them or because the browser is not capable of using them all.

This means that you generally should worry about rendering. It depends on the type of languages and characters used how much you need to worry about. English is less problematic than Esperanto, which is less problematic than Ethiopian, which is less problematic than Etruscan, in terms of font support. If the languages used are limited to, say, the 21 official languages of the EU, there is probably little to worry about.

Primarily, you should try to find a list of fonts so that each of the fonts covers all the characters needed and declare that list as the `font-family` value. For some additional general points, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).